# How do I close all tasks when there is no more links in the main_queue? I am using 40 workers

Tags: python-asyncio

"""I am scraping a site using aiohttp and asyncio with 40 workers and one consumer. How do I clean up and cancel all tasks when the main queue is empty?

I tried using:
for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
task.cancel

await asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks() - {asyncio.current_task()}, return_exceptions=True)

after this code:
"""

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

main_queue = asyncio.Queue()
parsed_links_queue = asyncio.Queue()
parsed_links = set()
limits = asyncio.Semaphore(40)

session = None
f_out = None
visited_urls = 0

async def get_url(url):
   global visited_urls
   async with limits:
       await asyncio.sleep(10)
       try:
          async with session.get(url) as resp:
          visited_urls += 1
          return await resp.text()
       except:
         print(f'Bad URL: {url}')

async def worker():
    while True:
        url = await main_queue.get()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(await get_url(url), 'html.parser')

        for a in soup.select('a[href]'):
             href = a['href']
             if href.startswith('/wiki/') and ':' not in href: 
        
        parsed_links_queue.put_nowait('https://es.wikipedia.org' + href)

    main_queue.task_done()

 async def consumer():
    while True:
        url = await parsed_links_queue.get()

        if url not in parsed_links:
             print(urllib.parse.unquote(url), file=f_out, flush=True)  # <-- print the url to file
             parsed_links.add(url)
             main_queue.put_nowait(url)

    parsed_links_queue.task_done()

async def main():
    global session, f_out

    url ='https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olula_del_R%C3%ADo'
    parsed_links.add(url)

    with open('out.txt', 'w') as f_out:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            workers = {asyncio.create_task(worker()) for _ in range(16)}
            c = asyncio.create_task(consumer())

            main_queue.put_nowait(seed_url)
            print('Initializing...')
            await asyncio.sleep(5)

            while main_queue.qsize():
                print(f'Visited URLs: {visited_urls:>7}  Known URLs (saved in out.txt): {len(parsed_links):>7}', flush=True)
                await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

    await main_queue.join()
    await parsed_links_queue.join()
    for task in asyncio.all_tasks():
       task.cancel

    await asyncio.gather(*asyncio.all_tasks() - 
 {asyncio.current_task()}, return_exceptions=True)


asyncio.run(main())

# original code was written by @ Andrej Kesely
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I suggest you read the articles on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then use the
 _Edit_ function to modify your question accordingly. Right now, you are missing a MRE, you are presenting irrelevant information (scraping application), and you said _what_ you tried, but did not explain what the problem with your approach was (unexpected result/error?).